# How to embed CAShapeLayer into the image of NSImageView?

Tags: swift, macos, printing, cashapelayer, nsimageview

There is a custom NSImageView. I can load an image and draw rectangle using CAShapeLayer

```
let selectionRectangle = CAShapeLayer()
selectionRectangle.lineWidth = 1.0
selectionRectangle.fillColor = NSColor.clear.cgColor
selectionRectangle.strokeColor = colorForBands_Numbers.cgColor
selectionRectangle.lineDashPattern = [1,1]
self.layer?.addSublayer(selectionRectangle) // the  CAShapeLayer is added to NSImageView layer
```

that results in the image and rectangle on top.

I would like to print this image with rectangle.

How can I do it ?

When I am using

```
let operation: NSPrintOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: self, printInfo: printInfo)
operation.run()
```

I have only image without the rectangle.